# Brightness controls not working on HP dm3t

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, brightness

I have an HP dm3t notebook which normally comes with Windows 7. I figured out how to install Windows XP on it, but now I'm facing a problem that the brightess controls don't work so am unable to change the brightess.

The strange thing is that all the other buttons (sound volume, mute, sleep, etc... ) works but not the 2 brightess controls.

I already downloaded the *HP Quick Launch Buttons*, but it didn't fix the problem. So I am asking about suggesitions how can I enable these two buttons in Windows XP or even if I can change the brightess using some kind of software.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- Update/install graphics drivers from the HP website.
- Check the `advanced` tab in the graphics properties. Depending what kinda graphics card you have installed you can adjust color/brightness/contrast there.
- Install an application to adjust screen brightness, google turns up a few.

Comment: the first two method wont work since i need to adjust the hardware screen brightess , using the graphic driver wont be able to let the screen brightess high when the notebooki is outdoor since physically the brightess will be low.
i will search google thought.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the answer whilst helping a friend. On my Mac and I swear some PCs, I simply press the bright/dim keys, but this didn't work on an HP Pavilion under Windows XP. After some research, I discovered it's necessary to press and hold the function key (Fn) and then tap the brightness/dim keys. The Fn step doesn't appear to be necessary with the sound keys keys.

For some odd reason, there doesn't appear to be a brightness control in Control Panels.